# Why does $\bigcup_{j \geq 1} A_j \cup B_j=(\bigcup_{j \geq 1} A_j) \cup (\bigcup_{j \geq 1} B_j)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the title says, I don't know why countable unions have this ("commutative") property.
Is there any counterexample? Could be a countable union or not.

Comment: Try proving that each side is contained in the other.

Comment: @robert Ah, I see, such like if $x \in \bigcup_{j \geq 1} A_j \cup B_j$ then there is $k$ : $x \in A_k \cup B_k$, then follows the proof. Is there any case that this property fails?

Comment: Follow Robert Shore's hint. Another hint: it holds for uncountable unions as well.

Comment: As noted by @KurtG., it holds for arbitrary unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when one wants to show that $A = B$, the routine procedure is to prove both the inclusions $A \subset B$ and $A \supset B$. This is achieved by proving the implications

$$ x \in A \implies x \in B \qquad \text{ and } \qquad y \in B \implies y \in A, $$

respectively. This is something you should always have in mind when you encounter these kind of problems.

---

Consider an arbitrary element $x \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \cup B_j$. By definition of union, there exists a constant $j_0 \geqslant 1$ such that $x \in A_{j_0} \cup B_{j_0}$. Moreover, again by definition of union, it follows that $x \in A_{j_0}$ or $x \in B_{j_0}$. These cases imply that $x \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j$ or $x \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} B_j$, respectively. Hence, we conclude $x \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} B_j \right)$, which is enough to guarantee the inclusion $(\subset)$.

On the other hand, consider now an arbitrary element $y \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} B_j \right).$ Then, by definition of union, it follows that $y \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \right)$ or $y \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} B_j \right)$. Now let us analyse these two possibilities individually:

1. Suppose first that $y \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \right).$ Then there exists a constant $j_1 \geqslant 1$ such that $y \in A_{j_1}$, which directly implies that $y \in A_{j_1} \cup B_{j_1}$. Hence, we conclude that

$$ y \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \cup B_j. $$

1. Assume now that $y \in \left( \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} B_j \right).$ Just like in the last point, it follows that there is a constant $j_2 \geqslant 1$ such that $y \in B_{j_2}$, which directly implies that $y \in A_{j_2} \cup B_{j_2}.$ Hence, we obtain

$$ y \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \cup B_j. $$

In both of the cases we've concluded that $y \in \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} A_j \cup B_j$ and so the inclusion $(\supset)$ is guaranteed.